# Intellij IDEA - how to override code style config

Tags: intellij-idea, editorconfig

We have a Java project in small team, all developers use Intellij IDEA.

I need to setup code style so that

- some settings (for example use tabs instead of spaces, import order, threshold for asterisk import etc.) are common for all developers, these settings are obligatory and versioned in Git
- tab size setting is up to each developer since it affects only appearance on his screen and not source code. It should not be versioned. Technically it should override common setting (actually its value should not be among obligatory values at all).

How to achieve it?

My attempts:

- I am aware of "Stored in Project" vs "Stored in IDE" configuration where the first one is [recommended](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html#configure-code-style-schemes) to be in VCS. However, if I define common settings as "Project" configuration, user can define custom "IDE" setting and activate it *instead of* the "Project" configuration, not *on top of* it.
- We also have `.editorconfig` file in project root with some common settings. Since the file is versioned in Git there would be great to have something like `.editorconfig-gitignored` file with custom settings (or put `.editorconfig` one level down into each subfolder, which is clumsy)
- Since Intellij Idea can override project settings with `.editorconfig` settings, it seems to be a solution to define common settings in Idea and custom setting in (newly gitignored) `.editorconfig` file. Unfortunately some properties in `.editorconfig` are mandatory as well so I feel it would be downgrade at this moment.